# Opening an Excel/Word file from FileStream (or similar)

Tags: c#, .net, office-interop

I'm using C#, .NET 4.0 and the office interop library to read the contents of the file.

I'm reading the office files from BLOBs, so I'm wondering if there's a way to directly input the filestream instead of opening it from disk? Perhaps I need to use another library for this?

EDIT: I should note that it needs to support older office formats as well!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help: [How to: Open a Word Processing Document from a Stream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff478386.aspx)

Comment: Open XML is from office 2007 and higher.  Will not support older .doc formats.